# How does time complexity for depth first search on a graph come out to be O(V+E) in the following code?

Tags: algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

How does time complexity for depth first search on a graph come out to be O(V+E) in the following code?

```
Using a Python dictionary to act as an adjacency list

graph = {
    'A' : ['B','C'],
    'B' : ['D', 'E'],
    'C' : ['F'],
    'D' : [],
    'E' : ['F'],
    'F' : []
}

visited = set() # Set to keep track of visited nodes.

def dfs(visited, graph, node):
    if node not in visited:
        print (node)
        visited.add(node)
        for neighbour in graph[node]:
            dfs(visited, graph, neighbour)

# Driver Code
dfs(visited, graph, 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if node not in visited:
```

due to this, no vertex is visited more than 1 time, also this condition won't be checked for more than in-degree times for any vertex, and we know the sum of in-degree is O(E), and

```
for neighbour in graph[node]:
```

due to this every edge connected to each node is considered as a possible step of [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

so the time complexity of O(V+E) (assuming O(1) insertion and deletion in your set)

Comment: Note that `if node not in visited` represents work, even when the condition is false.

Comment: @trincot Yes, now I have added more information.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the first call of `dfs`, every other call of `dfs` will uniquely correspond to one edge. Because of the `visited` mechanism, it is not possible that for the same value of `node` and `neighbor` the recursive call of `dfs` is made.

Actually this is the only determining factor for this algorithm, and so it is O(E).

In case the graph is disconnected, this algorithm will not visit all nodes. When that is a case that must be dealt with, the driver code should look like this:

```
for node in graph:
    dfs(visited, graph, node)
```

With this change the complexity becomes O(V+E). This is because there might be many more nodes than edges in a disconnected graph, and so O(E) would not capture the complexity, and the loop in the driver code becomes the determining factor. You'd thus say it is O(MAX(V, E)), which is the same as O(V+E).